# How to implement PriorityQueue using min-heap in Swift?

Tags: swift, algorithm, heap, priority-queue

First of all, is there a built-in "PriorityQueue"-like class in Swift standard library? I am unable to find one, therefore I'm writing it myself.

When I pop items from my queue, I expect the item to be the smallest at the moment. For most items, this is true, but some of them (very few) are not in the right positions and I can't seem to find out why. The below code snippet can be copy-pasted in Playground and run (including tests).

```swift
class PriorityQueue<T> {
    private var arr: [T] = []
    private let compare: (_ a: T, _ b: T) -> Bool

    init(_ compare: @escaping (_ a: T, _ b: T) -> Bool) {
        self.compare = compare
    }

    func insert(_ a: T) {
        arr.insert(a, at: 0)
        heapify(0)
    }

    func pop() -> T? {
        if arr.isEmpty {
            return nil
        }

        let res: T = arr.removeFirst()

        if !arr.isEmpty {
            arr.insert(arr.removeLast(), at: 0)
            heapify(0)
        }

        return res
    }

    private func heapify(_ i: Int) {
        let l: Int = 2 * i + 1, r: Int = 2 * i + 2
        var smallest: Int = i

        if l < arr.count, compare(arr[l], arr[smallest]) {
            smallest = l
        }

        if r < arr.count, compare(arr[r], arr[smallest]) {
            smallest = r
        }

        if smallest == i {
            return
        }

        let temp: T = arr[i]
        arr[i] = arr[smallest]
        arr[smallest] = temp

        heapify(smallest)
    }
}

// Test case
let size: Int = 15
var arr: [Int] = Array(repeating: 0, count: size)
let queue: PriorityQueue<Int> = PriorityQueue { $0 < $1 }

for i in 0..<size {
    arr[i] = Int.random(in: 1...10000)
    queue.insert(arr[i])
}

let sorted: [Int] = arr.sorted()
for i in 0..<size {
    let n: Int = queue.pop() ?? 0
    print(n, sorted[i], n == sorted[i])
}
```

95% of the times, items are being popped from the queue in correct order, but occasionally, I get results like this:

579  579 true

1372 1372 true

1762 1762 true

2113 2113 true

2332 2332 true

**2562 2418 false**

**2701 2562 false**

**3137 2701 false**

**2418 3137 false**

4615 4615 true

6085 6085 true

6820 6820 true

7382 7382 true

8878 8878 true

9220 9220 true

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding an item to a binary heap is very simple. You append the item to the end of the array and bubble it up the heap to its proper position. I don't know Swift, so I'll give you the pseudo-code. Assuming that backing array (or list) is called `arr`:

```
insert (val)
    append val to arr
    i = arr.count - 1
    while (i > 0)
        parent = (i-1)/2
        if (arr[i] < arr[parent])
            swap(arr[i], arr[parent])
            i = parent
        else
            break
```

Comment: Thank you for this, Jim. (And I was wondering why my LeetCode solution can only beat 20%)

Answer (score 1):

I'd consider writing this heapifyUp as such:

```
mutating private func heapifyUp(_ index: Int) {
    var childIndex = index
    let child = items[childIndex]
    var parentIndex = getParentIndex(childIndex)

    while childIndex > 0 && orderCriteria(child, items[parentIndex]) {
        items[childIndex] = items[parentIndex]
        childIndex = parentIndex
        parentIndex = getParentIndex(childIndex)
    }

    items[childIndex] = child
}
```

orderCriteria is simply:

```
private var orderCriteria: (T, T) -> Bool
```

And you can initialize your Heap as such:

```
public init(sort: @escaping (T, T) -> Bool) {
    self.orderCriteria = sort
}
```

That way you can use this as a MinHeap or a MaxHeap by defining the orderCriteria.

And your insert/add function becomes:

```
mutating public func add(_ item: T) {
    items.append(item)
    heapifyUp(items.count - 1)
}
```

I hope this helps! I think your solution is also very similar. Note the `items` I'm using is your `arr` and it seems your heapify() function works as well but mine is a iterative version and yours is a recursive version. Though I haven't tested yours to be honest.

Answer (score 0):

I just figured out why I was wrong, the error occurs in `func insert(_ a: T)`, where I simply prepend the new element and then try to heapify the array from first element.

The function should be re-written:

```
func insert(_ a: T) {
    arr.append(a)
    for i in stride(from: arr.count / 2 - 1, through: 0, by: -1) {
        heapify(i)
    }
}
```

However, this is not very efficient, as we're breaking the entire heapified array and re-heapifing what was mostly heapified. Therefore, instead of prepending the element, I append it, this way, we're breaking, at maximum, one sub-tree of the heap. From there, we try to heapify the array bottom to top:

```
private func heapifyUp(_ i: Int) {
    if i == 0 {
        return
    }

    let parent: Int, sibling: Int
    if i.isMultiple(of: 2) {
        parent = (i - 2) / 2
        sibling = parent * 2 + 1
    } else {
        parent = (i - 1) / 2
        sibling = parent * 2 + 2
    }

    var smallest: Int = parent

    if compare(arr[i], arr[smallest]) {
        smallest = i
    }

    if sibling < arr.count, compare(arr[sibling], arr[smallest]) {
        smallest = sibling
    }

    if smallest == parent {
        return
    }

    let temp: T = arr[parent]
    arr[parent] = arr[smallest]
    arr[smallest] = temp

    heapifyUp(parent)
    heapify(smallest)
}
```

The mistake I made was that I assumed after I prepend an element, rest of the array (except for the new element) is still heapified, which is not true. Consider this case:

You have a heapified array: [5, 8, 6, 9, 12, 7] and when you prepend a new element 10 and call `heapify(0)`, the array becomes: [5, 6, 8, 10, 9, 12, 7], where 8 is the parent of 12 and 7, but 8 is not smaller than 7.

Comment: You have the right idea, but your code is overly complex. See my answer.